# LargeImages to WPF ListView port

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, thumbnails

I need to port classic ListView to WPF version, I googled a lot, however I couldn't find a simple code snippet. All I need is emulating LargeImageList to show dynamic/webcam captured (Image) pictures.

.net 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just use StackPanel

```
 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Border Margin="5" CornerRadius="5" Height="40" Width ="45" >
        <Image Source="Images/Desert.jpg"></Image>
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="5" CornerRadius="5" Height="40" Width ="45" >
        <Image Source="Images/Desert.jpg"></Image>
    </Border>
    <Border Margin="5" CornerRadius="5" Height="40" Width ="45" >
        <Image Source="Images/Desert.jpg"></Image>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: You can Add Items to StackPanel at runtime

Comment: OK I see, it looks like much HTML, however I also need to work with index, to find & delete necessary images. Seems there is no built-in index thingy, so should I search sequentially whole collection for the right item or is there any better method?

Answer (score 2):

Actually what you want to use is a wrap panel:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  ...
</ListView>
```

Also if your images aren't already the same size you can use the trick written in this article to make them all the same size:
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/09/06/synchronizing-the-width-of-elements-in-an-itemscontrol/